# Force equal hinting when combining symbols

Tags: pdf, typography, rendering

I am building a custom operator out of two triangles. But it seems that to the PDF viewers (evince in this case), they are still individual characters and hinted (i.e. pixel-aligned) differently, which hurts the visual appearance.

For example, this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\triangleleft\triangleright$~$\triangleleft\triangleright$
\end{document}
```

will be rendered, at some zoom level, as follows:

[image: differently hinted instances of the same symbol]

Is there a way to tell LaTeX resp. the PDF interpreter that these two symbols should be hinted together, and consistently?

Comment: Hinting? I don't know this term, but you mean `kerning` perhaps. Perhaps there's such a symbol already

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Hinting refers to how vector things are rendered on a raster display.

Comment: [I get this from your code](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pO8Fy.png). May you have font problems.

Comment: No, there's no such thing. The same happens quite frequently also with adjacent letters, but the curvy shapes help in not noticing the phenomenon, which is more evident with straight lines.

Comment: @HarishKumar Yes, you get that at high resolution.  But the OP is showing the image at very low zoom level, wherein the inter-symbol gap seems not fixed in size.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I should clarify that --> Font hinting (also known as instructing) is the use of mathematical instructions to adjust the display of an outline font so that it lines up with a rasterized grid. At low screen resolutions, hinting is critical for producing clear, legible text.

Comment: If you are open to a possible solution that rasterizes your operator, let me know and I will post it.  I would never purposefully rasterize a vector glyph, but if you are desperate...

Comment: No, I’m not desparate, and, I definitely do not want to include a bitmap in my document :-)

Comment: Understood.  In that case, one can make the issue less pronounced by adding a little extra space between the parts, as in `$\triangleleft\kern.5pt\triangleright$`.  By the way, if you want to direct your comment at someone in particular who is not the owner of the question or answer (so that they are notified), you need to include their @username, like @Steven B. Segletes, in the comment.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes understood. How difficult would it be to define a font that contains just this one glyph, and use that? I would imagine that this might avoid the hinting issues.

Comment: Sad to say, I am no expert on what it takes to create a usable font.

Comment: No solution yet.

Comment: Especially for CFF fonts, hinting is very much up to the rasterizer in the PDF viewer, so there's not much you can put in the actual PDF (let alone the LaTeX source) that will influence it. TTF fonts (or rather, systems like Microsoft's ClearType built especially for TTF fonts) tend to come with more detailed instructions in the font itself. Anyway, getting a higher-dpi monitor may be the best you can do :-)